# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.qty' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento2

When I try generate products feed then I get error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.qty' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = 1 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tbl_status_1` ON e.entity_id = tbl_status_1.entity_id AND tbl_status_1.attribute_id=94 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tbl_visibility_2` ON e.entity_id = tbl_visibility_2.entity_id AND tbl_visibility_2.attribute_id=96 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `tbl_category_ids_4` ON e.entity_id = tbl_category_ids_4.product_id WHERE (((tbl_status_1.value = '1') AND (tbl_visibility_2.value = '4') AND (e.qty >= '1
```

I try:

> delete var/cache
>
> indexer:reset
>
> indexer:reindex

and also I try use flat product: no

> reindex again

Still issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your query's got a wrong syntax. It's missing "')))".
Well, the error is pretty clear, your table 'e' (catalog_product_entity) does not have a column called 'qty'.

But your query is full of errors:

Table 'catalog_product_entity_int' does not have a column 'entity_id' by default in Magento 2. It's now row_id.

This is as good as I can fix your query. It's missing qty column, as I mentioned, does not exist in the referred table.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = 1 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tbl_status_1` ON e.entity_id = tbl_status_1.`row_id` AND tbl_status_1.`attribute_id`=94 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tbl_visibility_2` ON e.entity_id = tbl_visibility_2.row_id AND tbl_visibility_2.attribute_id=96 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `tbl_category_ids_4` ON e.entity_id = tbl_category_ids_4.product_id 
WHERE (tbl_status_1.`value` = '1') AND (tbl_visibility_2.value = '4')
```